# What shortcut does ⌦ symbol in Camunda macOS app indicate and how to invoke it?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I am using the Camunda macOS app and I am wondering what does this shortcut mean (right facing delete key)?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In macOS, this symbol represents forward delete shortcut (to delete characters to right). It can be generated using the <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> key combination.

The aforementioned shortcuts are helpful on majority of Apple keyboards which lacks a dedicated forward delete key, such as MacBook and Apple Magic keyboard.

To reiterate:

- <kbd>⌫</kbd>: Delete Left (like Backspace on Widows/PC)
- <kbd>⌦</kbd>: Delete Right (<kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> on compact keyboards. Also called Forward Delete)

---

This keystroke is used in the Camunda macOS app to remove selected object from canvas.

[image]

Notice the <kbd>fn</kbd> and <kbd>delete</kbd> keys in the accessibility keyboard.

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to say without more context on how/where this appears within the application, but Apple uses this symbol for the (forward) Delete key, e.g. on the [Magic Keyboard with Keypad](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MQ052LL/A/magic-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-us-english-silver?fnode=56):

[image]